# How to create a sequence of nodes to work as a "tour" through a site?

Tags: nodes

I can think of different ways, like creating a View with all nodes available and sort them with DraggableViews so I have a tree, and then adding a Next/Prev buttons if the user wants to see the site not as individual nodes, but as a Tour, being taken from the first node to the last one in a specific order.

Anyone has any better, less of a hassle, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Custom Pagers](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_pagers)

> Custom Pagers allows administrators to define context-sensitive
>   previous/next pagers for any node type. The list of nodes to be cycled
>   through is generated by a user-selectable view, and each pager can be
>   displayed above or below the node body or in a sidebar block. This
>   makes it possible to duplicate the paging functions of forum.module
>   and book.module, as well as more complex stuff like comic strip
>   navigation. Requires token.module and views.module.

and [Nodequeue](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodequeue)

> The Nodequeue module allows users to collect nodes in an arbitrarily
>   ordered list.

Comment: It's interesting, but I need a tree like structure, this only allows one dimension...

Comment: Core Book module in that case.